# Chatbox multithread java, GUI and socket connection issues

Tags: java, sockets, user-interface

I try to create a chatbox in java thanks to socket. My project was working when I use the terminal but now i try to connect this part with my GUI. For now my project is separated in 2 parts clients and server.

On my GUI part:

- First I have a Preframe (The user enter an username and click on enter). If the username is valid (no '@' and contain at least 2 letters), I open the connection with this function:

  ```
  public void connection(String username){
      Socket socket = null;
      try
      {
          socket = new Socket("localhost",2222);
          clientSocket = socket;
          os= new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
          is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
          inputLine = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

          if (clientSocket != null && os != null && is != null) {
              try {
                  /* Create a thread to read from the server. */
                  new Thread(new IncomingReader()).start();
                  while (!closed) {
                      os.println(inputLine.readLine().trim());
                      System.out.println(inputLine.readLine().trim());
                  }
                  /*
                   * Close the output stream, close the input stream, close the socket.
                   */

                  os.close();
                  is.close();
                  clientSocket.close();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  System.err.println("IOException: " + e);
              }
          }

      }catch (UnknownHostException e) {
          System.err.println("Don't know about host " + "localhost");
      } catch (IOException e) {
          System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to the host "+ "localhost");
      }
  }
  ```
- Here is the thread that I start:

  ```
  public class IncomingReader implements Runnable{

      @Override
      public void run() {
          /*
           * Keep on reading from the socket till we receive "Bye" from the * server. Once we received that then we want to break.
           */
          String responseLine;
          try {
              while ((responseLine = inputLine.readLine()) != null) {
                  //chatBox.append(responseLine);
                  System.out.println(responseLine);

                  if (responseLine.indexOf("*** Bye") != -1)
                      break;
              }
              closed = true;
          } catch (IOException e) {
              System.err.println("IOException: " + e);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

On server side:

- I accept the connection

  ```
  while (true) {
      try {
          clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
          if(threads.isEmpty()){
              clientThread t = new clientThread(clientSocket,threads,names);
              t.start();
              threads.add(t);
          }else{
              clientThread t = new clientThread(clientSocket,threads,names);
              t.start();
              threads.add(t);
          }

          if (threads.size() == maxClientsCount) {
              PrintStream os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
              os.println("Server too busy. Try later.");
              os.close();
              clientSocket.close();
          }
      } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println(e);
      }  //System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to the host ");
  }
  ```
- I create a new clientThread:

  ```
  public void run() {
      LinkedHashSet<clientThread> threads = this.threads;
      try {
          /*
           * Create input and output streams for this client.
           */
          is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
          os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

          System.out.println(is.readLine().trim());

          String name = is.readLine().trim();
          System.out.println(name);

          /* Welcome the new the client. */
          os.println("Welcome " + name + " to our chat room.\nTo leave enter /quit in a new line.");
  ```

For now all I notice is when I try to read the name, I can't and then my application freeze. Why is it not working?

Ps: I'm not really good with socket and network in general.

Comment: What UI framework? You are most likely blocking the main event thread

Comment: I use Java Swing.

Comment: Then I recommend having a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: I will check it out with this. I maybe notice with I do not run. I think I do not send my username to the server. So it maybe try to read an empty socket.